# CI_Sessions print specific user_data for all sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Hey guys im quite new into programming and i would like some assistance...I store my sessions into a database table and each session row has a user_data array which contains the values email and logged_in.

I want to search that table for every session entry and print only the email from the user_data array (to server as a "who's online") but i get very confused with the multiple arrays.

```
$email = $this->session->userdata('email'); //That's how i read the single session now
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that this could will be useful for you.
i get the data from ci_session table and after that i ge the last activity you can get your 
email the same way.

my model function where i get data from ci_session table

```
 function get_alls()
 {
     $this->db->select('t1.*');
     $this->db->from('ci_session AS t1');
     $query = $this->db->get();
     return $query;
 }
```

inside my controller i called it.

```
 $recs = $this->main_model->get_alls();

 //echo unserialize($recs->row()->user_data); exit;
 foreach($recs->result() AS $item)
 {
     if($item->last_activity+300<strtotime("now"))
     {
          $mhd = unserialize($item->user_data);
                 $this->ci_forms = array('loged'=> '0');
                 $this->crud_model->UpdateUid('users',$this->ci_forms,$mhd['userid']);
     }
}
```